# Mobile web app, styling in percentages; I can't get height to work

Tags: css, mobile

I am building a mobile app for a band and obviously want it to display well in all the plethora of handsets out there today. I built it at first for my own device and it looks and works great, so now I am reworking it in percentages so that it works in all devices.

I have a slider (jquerytools) going on and if i set width to 100% then it is perfectly wide in my iphone and my ipad... success, however I am not having any luck with height. It seems to only accept a height in px. If i set a height in percent it just doesn't display.

any ideas?

Updated CSS:

```
#header{
width:100%;

position:relative;
z-index: 20;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.scrollable {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px purple;
/*  height:198px; */
z-index: 20;
}


.scrollable .items {
/* this cannot be too large */
width:1000%;
position:absolute;
clear:both;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px green;

}

.items div {
float:left;
width:10%;
height:100%;

}

/* single scrollable item */
.scrollable img {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
   height: auto;
 /*    height:198px; */
}

/* active item */
.scrollable .active {
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: People might be more willing to try a couple things with it if you throw your code into a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) to experiment with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your element mustn't be `position:relative`, i'd do like that

```
.scrollable {
   position:absolute; // instead of relative
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 100%;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;// instead of height: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px purple;
   /*  height:198px; */
   z-index: 20;
}
```

basically I defined the position as absolute, and added the fact the element begins at zero from top and at zero from bottom, which would be equivalent to `height:100%;`